# Generate manifest for regfree COM from a VB project

Tags: vb.net, com, regfreecom

I am trying to generate a manifest for a set of COM objects that are being used in our code as registration-free COM.
For that purpose I created a VB project in VS 2010 and added the COM objects DLLs as dependencies. The problem is I do not see them listed as dependencies in the generated manifest. Am I missing something simple like a project setting to generate the proper manifest listing the dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out too many details and the VB.NET IDE hides too much to do this right.  It is not automatic.

Starting point is to force it to show more.  Locate the "Show All Files" toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window (use the tooltip to find it back).  Click it and you now get the "References" node added to the project.

Open it and locate the COM component that you added to the project.  Select it and look at the Properties window.  Set the "Isolated" property to True.  Rebuild the project.  Be sure to look in the Output window for any warnings.  And to look at the .manifest file on disk instead of the one the IDE shows you if you added a manifest to your project yourself.

Comment: Thank you Hans,
I was able to get the first dependency into the manifest. My stumbling block turned out to be that the dll was not registered using regsvr32

Comment: That generates a build error.  So it appears that setting Isolated to *True* was the missing ingredient.  Please close your question.